# Filling a Funds ddl based upon the selection of a client ddl

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to click a dropdown to pick a client and based on the selection I want to fill a 2nd dropdown with the fund names that they hold. I'm not sure where/how to call the `ClientInvestmentsSince2` method that fills the 2nd dropdown.

I picked up this code from microsoft forums and massaged it some. I'm not sure how the Json works - never used it. Can you help? 
Thanks.

ReportsController code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace StockHoldings.Controllers
{
    public class ReportsController : Controller
    {

        // GET: Reports/ClientInvestmentsSince
        public ActionResult ClientInvestmentsSince()
        {
            string str = @"Data Source=USER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=HoldingsConnectionString;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
            string query = "select * from Clients";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = rdr[1].ToString(), Value = rdr[0].ToString() });
            }
            ViewData["client"] = li;

           //ClientInvestmentsSince2(2);
           return View();
        }
        // JsonResult FundList(int Id)
        public JsonResult ClientInvestmentsSince2(int Id)
        {
            string str = @"Data Source=USER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=HoldingsConnectionString;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
            string query = "select * from Investments where Client_ID ='" + Id + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = rdr[2].ToString(), Value = rdr[0].ToString() });
            }
            ViewData["fund"] = li;
            return Json(li, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        // POST: Reports/ClientInvestmentsSince
}
}

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ View Code ++++++++++++++++++++++++




@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ @Html.DropDownList("Client", ViewData["client"] as SelectList, "Select Client", new { id = "Client_ID", style = "width: 150px;" })<br />}
    { @Html.DropDownList("Fund", ViewData["fund"] as SelectList, "Select Fund" )};
        @* (comment) <select id="Fund" name="Fund" , style="width: 150px;"></select><br />*@
        }
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script type="text/jscript">
    $(function ()
    {
        $('#Client').change(function ()
        {
            $.getJSON('/Cascading/ClientList/' + $('#Client').val(), function (data)
            {
                var items = '<option>Select Fund</option>';
                $.each(data, function (i, fund)
                {
                    items += "<option value='" + fund.Value + "'>" + fund.Text + "</option>";
                });
                //assign the result to the Fund selectlist
                $('#Fund').html(items);
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```

*** Here's the modified code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ @Html.DropDownList("Client", ViewData["client"] as SelectList, "Select Client", new { id = "Client_ID", style = "width: 150px;" })<br />
    @*{ @Html.DropDownList("Fund", "Select Fund")};*@
        <select id="Fund" name="Fund" , style="width: 150px;"></select><br />
        }
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script type="text/jscript">
    $(function ()
    {
        $('#Client').change(function ()
        {
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("ClientInvestmentsSince2", "Reports")', { id: $(this).val() }, function (data)
            {
                var items = '<option>Select Fund</option>';
                $.each(data, function (i, fund)
                {
                    items += "<option value='" + fund.Value + "'>" + fund.Text + "</option>";
                });
                //assign the result to the Fund selectlist
                $('#Fund').html(items);
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Your method is named `ClientInvestmentsSince2()` so its `$.getJSON('@Url.Action("ClientInvestmentsSince2", "Reports")', { id: $(this).val() }, function (data) { ...`

Comment: Stephen, thanks so much for your input. I made the change however when I click the first ddl, the second (Fund) ddl does not populate with anything. Could you take a look? Thanks. The modified code is in the top textbox under the title "*** Here's the modified code". Look for it at the bottom.

Comment: What errors do you get in the browser console? And refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for  a working example of how to implement cascading dropdownlists)